# xmlhttprequest in cordova lead to empty post via HTTPS

Tags: cordova, https, xmlhttprequest

In my cordova app when I send a xhr POST request to the server the $_POST variable is empty when I the connection is done via SSL. My development version server is not under SSL and everything is working fine, on the other hand in my running version which has a valid SSL certificate the $_POST variable is empty.

In config.xml I have allow-navigation href=" * "  and I reach the erver without error.

JS code :

```
var newName = 'John Smith',
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.responseText !== newName)
        console.log( xhr.responseText);
    else if (xhr.status !== 200)
        console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
};
xhr.send(encodeURI('name=' + newName));
```

PHP code :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Result when url is http :

```
Array
(
    [name] => John Smith
)
```

But when url is https :

```
Array
(
)
```

The question is why it is empty and how do I do to get it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found, I had to change my target url from https://my-domain.com to https://www.my-domain.com
I guess it was due to a server redirection between the two names leading to the lost of my POST data.